# Запятая после "ладно", деепричастный оборот

Tags: запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в следующем предложении:

**Ладно, когда она молчала, так теперь, делая какие-то предположения, Катя отвлекала меня и злила.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хорошо бы использовать союз НО для связи предложений:

**Ладно, когда она молчала, но теперь,** делая какие-то предположения, Катя отвлекала меня и злила.

Запятая после ладно ставится, деепричастный оборот выделен верно.

Здесь наречие ***ладно*** в функции сказуемого.

ЛАДНО. Разг. I. нареч.  6. (обычно **с придат. предл.** и союзами: что, хоть, ещё и т.п.). К счастью, удачно, что; **хорошо ещё**. Л., хоть дождя не было.

Примеры:

**Ладно, когда** неприятности у меня, но когда у моих друзей… [Анатолий Мельник. Авторитет (2000)]

**Ладно, когда** я взяла одно платье, но они стали приносить второе, третье… [Татьяна Шмыга. Счастье мне улыбалось... (2000)]